# Image Transforms not generated - permission problem?

Tags: craft3, image-transforms

Since I installed my Craft based website on the production server the image transforms are no longer generated. The tasks runs through more than 5000 images but doesn't generate new ones.
There have been other issues with permissions on this server we solved but we can't figure out what the problem is now, since there are no errors about this.

**Does Craft use any temp folders or so when generating the image transforms?** When I know which folders are affected I can check the permissions again.

```
PHP version                 7.4.10
OS version                  Linux 4.9.0-9-amd64
Database driver & version   MySQL 5.5.5
Image driver & version      Imagick 3.4.4 (ImageMagick 6.9.7-4)
Craft edition & version     Craft Pro 3.5.11.1
Yii version                 2.0.38
Twig version                2.12.5
Guzzle version              6.5.5
Imagine version             1.2.3-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

Craft will store any temporary files it generates into `storage/runtime/temp` by default, but both Imagick and GD will also likely write to the system's temp folder (likely `/tmp` but could vary depending on OS and distro).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I still couldn't solve the problem. Is there a way to find out what causes this problem? Are there any logs of the failed image transforms?